# Image gallery in html. How to make images appear the same size?

Tags: css, image, size, gallery

How to make images from image gallery  appear same size? (if originally they have different dimensions).

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/MrKoala/dmeyh4xf/#&togetherjs=5IHCUwkag8)

Add a description of the image here

```
<div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.it/g/300/400">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/200/300" alt="Forest" width="600"  height="400">
</a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
 </div>
    <div class="img">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400" alt="Northern Lights" width="600"height="400">
</a>
<div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
 </div>

  <div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
</a>
<div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
 </div>
 <div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
</a>
<div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update Css** Add `img` Class In Css. And Remove `height :auto` in `div.img img` Class

**Note:** You Can Change Hight & width in Css

```
img
{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
div.img img
{
 width: 100%;
}
```

**See Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/d1ojLbkt/)

**Snippet Example Below**

```css
div.img {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}

div.img:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.img img {
  width: 100%;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
img
{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>

  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random" alt="Trolltunga Norway" >
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.it/g/300/400">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/200/300" alt="Forest" >
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400" alt="Northern Lights" >
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400" alt="Northern Lights" >
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400" alt="Northern Lights" >
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400" alt="Northern Lights" >
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400" alt="Northern Lights" >
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you want to adjust the ones that aren't the same size. In other words, if you have a 300x200 image and a 300x300 image, you could:

- stretch the 300x200 one out to 300x300, which would make it look distorted
- scale the 300x200 one up so it's large enough to fill a 300x300 box, then crop out or hide the excess
- keep the 300x200 one at its normal size but put it in a 300x300 box with some whitespace above and below it
- crop the top and bottom of the 300x300 one so it's also 300x200

These are all options you have and they'd all be implemented a little differently, so first figure out which way you want to go.